# Проблема с Makefile в Windows

Tags: windows, makefile

Пытаюсь установить Google Test на Windows, при запуске make возникает такая ошибка.

[image: изображение с ошибкой]

Вот код Makefile:

```
# A sample Makefile for building Google Test and using it in user
# tests.  Please tweak it to suit your environment and project.  You
# may want to move it to your project's root directory.
#
# SYNOPSIS:
#
#   make [all]  - makes everything.
#   make TARGET - makes the given target.
#   make clean  - removes all files generated by make.

# Please tweak the following variable definitions as needed by your
# project, except GTEST_HEADERS, which you can use in your own targets
# but shouldn't modify.

# Points to the root of Google Test, relative to where this file is.
# Remember to tweak this if you move this file.
GTEST_DIR = ..

# Where to find user code.
USER_DIR = ../samples

# Flags passed to the preprocessor.
# Set Google Test's header directory as a system directory, such that
# the compiler doesn't generate warnings in Google Test headers.
CPPFLAGS += -isystem $(GTEST_DIR)/include

# Flags passed to the C++ compiler.
CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread

# All tests produced by this Makefile.  Remember to add new tests you
# created to the list.
TESTS = sample1_unittest

# All Google Test headers.  Usually you shouldn't change this
# definition.
GTEST_HEADERS = $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/*.h \
                $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/internal/*.h

# House-keeping build targets.

all : $(TESTS)

clean :
  rm -f $(TESTS) gtest.a gtest_main.a *.o

# Builds gtest.a and gtest_main.a.

# Usually you shouldn't tweak such internal variables, indicated by a
# trailing _.
GTEST_SRCS_ = $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.cc $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)

# For simplicity and to avoid depending on Google Test's
# implementation details, the dependencies specified below are
# conservative and not optimized.  This is fine as Google Test
# compiles fast and for ordinary users its source rarely changes.
gtest-all.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
  $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
            $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc

gtest_main.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
  $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
            $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc

gtest.a : gtest-all.o
  $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

gtest_main.a : gtest-all.o gtest_main.o
  $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

# Builds a sample test.  A test should link with either gtest.a or
# gtest_main.a, depending on whether it defines its own main()
# function.

sample1.o : $(USER_DIR)/sample1.cc $(USER_DIR)/sample1.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
  $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/sample1.cc

sample1_unittest.o : $(USER_DIR)/sample1_unittest.cc \
                     $(USER_DIR)/sample1.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
  $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/sample1_unittest.cc

sample1_unittest : sample1.o sample1_unittest.o gtest_main.a
  $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@
```

Comment: Да, под никсы сделанный makefile. Не во всяком окружении в винде сработает. Не вижу повода рассказывать об этом, так бывает.

Comment: Спасибо, гуглом пользоваться умею. По первой ссылке как раз и делал все, но не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

[Такой](https://www.google.com/search?q=compile%20googletest%20windows&oq=googletest%20compile&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.8919j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8) или [такой](https://www.google.com/search?q=install%20google%20test%20windows&oq=install%20googletest%20&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.8134j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8) запрос к [поисковой системе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0) [google](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google) даёт достаточно информации для того чтобы узнать как же всё таки устанавливается под windows этот фреймворк.

Например, [раз](https://code.google.com/p/tonatiuh/wiki/InstallingGoogleTestForWindows) или [два](http://binglongx.com/2013/10/24/build-google-test-on-windows/).

Comment: cmake какую ошибку возвращает?      там есть и другие рекомендации, например http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248237/how-to-compile-googletest-on-windows-using-mingw-with-msys, с ними тоже никак?